# When has ast.BoolOp more than two values?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python's AST defines boolean expressions with

```
BoolOp(boolop op, expr* values)
```

I would have expected it to be similar to `BinOp`, with a `left` and a `right` value.

Can someone give me an example code where the AST would have a number of values different from two?

Edit:

Apparently `x and y and z` results in three values. So let me rephrase:

Why is this not modelled as two nested `BoolOp` expressions?

Comment: boolean operators must be special cases because of the shortcuts; when evaluating `A and B and C`, `B` and `C` will not evaluate if `A` is `False`.

Comment: They are evaluated differently than BinOp, sure. But `A and B and C` can be seen as `A and (B and C)` without changing this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a and b and c` is considered a ternary conjunction by the Python parser:

```
>>> e = ast.parse('''a and b and c''').body[0].value
>>> e.op
<_ast.And object at 0x254d1d0>
>>> e.values
[<_ast.Name object at 0x2d9ba50>, <_ast.Name object at 0x2d9ba90>, <_ast.Name object at 0x2d9bad0>]
```

Although parentheses will force it to parse as a recursive binary conjunction:

```
>>> ast.parse('''a and (b and c)''').body[0].value.values
[<_ast.Name object at 0x2d9b990>, <_ast.BoolOp object at 0x2d9bb10>]
```

I'm not sure why this is. In any case, a `BoolOp` may not have less than two children according to a unit test in the CPython source code.

I initially thought it would be an optimization, but then the `a and b and c` is completely equivalent to `a and (b and c)`; they even generate identical bytecode:

```
>>> def f(a, b, c):
...     return a and b and c
... 
>>> def g(a, b, c):
...     return a and (b and c)
... 
>>> from dis import dis
>>> dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    15
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              9 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    15
             12 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
        >>   15 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              3 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    15
              6 LOAD_FAST                1 (b)
              9 JUMP_IF_FALSE_OR_POP    15
             12 LOAD_FAST                2 (c)
        >>   15 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: I think OP got that and was asking *why*, since that makes `BoolOp` different from a `BinOp` (and thus arguably violates rules of simplicity).

Comment: Is `a and b and c` behaving differently in anyway from `a and (b and c)`?

Comment: @Lawnmower: none whatsoever. It might be an optimization, give me a sec to `grep` the CPython source code.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Good idea with the `dis`. Got to remember that.